# FTP IPs won't open in Explorer

Tags: windows, ftp

Windows 10 keeps asking me for a default program to open an FTP IP. It's been working fine up until about 20 minutes ago, now its badgering me to have a default app for it, and I can't set explorer for it. Before you ask, YES, FTP view outside of browser option in Internet Options is checked. I want to know how do I delete this stupid thing in regedit. I want to DELETE the default program promt for FTP PERMANENTLY.

I just want my FTP in explorer, how do I get this back?

Comment: Have you found a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method:
Navigate to **Setting->Default apps->Choose default apps by protocol->FTP->select the default app as Internet Explorer**:

[image]